# Fade out Using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use change the opacity of a class that is passed into the function parameter as element. It seems to crash as it reaches "target.style.opacity = newSetting"
I'm not sure what is causing this issue because when I use a getElementById instead it works.

here's the Javascript

```
var fade_out_from = 10;
function fadeOut(element)
{
    moving = true;
    var target = document.getElementsByClassName(element);
    var newSetting = fade_out_from / 10;
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;
    fade_out_from--;
    if(fade_out_from == 0){
        target.style.opacity = 0;
        target.style.display = "none";
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_out_from = 10;
        moving = false;
        return false;
    }
    var loopTimer = setTimeout(fadeOut(element),10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I came out with that seemed to do the trick. You would just have to add aditional "target[2].style.opacity = setting" to account for additional elements in the same class.

```
var fade_out_from = 10;
var fadeTimer = setTimeout(function fadeOut(element){
    var target = document.getElementsByClassName(element);
    if(fade_out_from == 0){
        target[0].style.opacity = 0;
        target[1].style.opacity = 0;
        fade_out_from = 10;
        moving = false;
        clearTimeout(fadeTimer);
        return false;
    }
    moving = true;
    var newSetting = fade_out_from / 10;
    target[0].style.opacity = newSetting;
    target[1].style.opacity = newSetting;
    fade_out_from--;
    return true;
},50);
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) that is why `target.style.opacity` is undefined. Instead try to use `target[0].style.opacity` (unless you actually need to deal with more than one found element; in that case the script will become slightly more complex).

But even then the script won't fade out the element because of the way you are using `setTimeout` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout). The first parameter there is supposed to be a callback (just a name of a function). If you want to pass parameters, you need to add them as 3rd, 4th, etc. parameters (won't work in IE<9).

So your script may look the following way:

```
var fade_out_from = 10;
function fadeOut(element)
{
    moving = true;
    var target = document.getElementsByClassName(element);
    var newSetting = fade_out_from / 10;
    target[0].style.opacity = newSetting;
    fade_out_from--;
    if(fade_out_from == 0){
        target[0].style.opacity = 0;
        target[0].style.display = "none";
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fade_out_from = 10;
        moving = false;
        return false;
    }
    var loopTimer = window.setTimeout(fadeOut,10, element);
}
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thanks you. I wasn't aware it returned a list.

Comment: This answer has some incorrect information in it - you can pass in a function expression to `setTimeout` like `setTimeout(function() { fadeOut(element) },10);` The benefit of this is that it will work in IE<9

Comment: @Adam that's true, forgot to mention. Thanks!